# Exclude non printable characters except new line

Tags: c#, regex, ascii

I've an issue like this:
[string filter: detect non-ASCII signs in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999566/string-filter-detect-non-ascii-signs) 
but I should exclude all no-printable characters in a string **except new line** chars (\n).

Starting from Regex option:

```
foo = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(foo, @"[^\u0020-\u007E]+", string.Empty);
```

I've modified it in this way:

```
foo = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(foo, @"[\u0000-\u0009\u000B-\u000C\u000E-\u0019\u007F]+", string.Empty);
```

This seems to work correctly, but could you suggest a less verbose solution?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to do it without regex if you aren't good with it

Comment: Did you mean "except new line (\n) and carriage return (\r) characters"?

Comment: Correct. I should keep Carriage Return and Line Feed.

Comment: Aren't you failing to filter out some unprintable characters, namely 0x1a to 0x1f inclusive?

Comment: Try `[\p{Cc}-[\r\n]]+`

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew. Thanks for your answer. Works great.

Comment: is there an equivalent in Python for this please?

Answer (score 3):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\p{C}+");    
string strWithPrintableChars = string.Join('\n'.ToString(),
                    foo.Split('\n').Select(line => regex.Replace(line, "")));
```

Explanation:

- Declare the Regex for non-printable characters
  [C# regex to remove non - printable characters, and control characters, in a text that has a mix of many different languages, unicode letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564692/c-sharp-regex-to-remove-non-printable-characters-and-control-characters-in-a)
- Split string at each line break characters which returns an IEnumerable for each line. 
      Characters matching regex are replaced for each line Lines are concatenated again as a single string with line break character,
  using string.join.

Comment: Please add an explanation so that it's easier for posterity to understand

Comment: In the context of .net core and multiplatforms  I would suggest to change this part: foo.Split('\n') to foo.Split(new char[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)  and string.Join('\n'.ToString()    to string.Join(Environment.NewLine, foo......

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, actually the question was asked for '\n' explicitly and has been used in the answer to explain. However, please find my remark on your points. 
1. "foo.Split('\n') to foo.Split(new char[] { '\n', '\r' }" -- this is better if we are dealing with both line feed and carriage return.
2. "string.Join(Environment.NewLine, foo......" -- this should not be used because it may induce '\r' in the result on windows which is not the objective of the question.